# Commit to Github from Atom signed with GPG

Tags: git, github, atom-editor

Followed by [Managing commit signature verification](https://help.github.com/en/articles/managing-commit-signature-verification) guide, I've created GPG key, added it to my GitHub account and have set my git to using it when signing commits. So now I can do signed commit from terminal like so:
`git commit -S -m "Comment was added. Commit from console."`, and push changes to the GitHub.

But how can I sign in commits with same GPG in Atom? Now after staging  - committing - pushing it's not **verified**:

[image]

Cannot find info about it in the manual: [GitHub package](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/github-package/)

Comment: Perhaps it simply cannot. Even [GitHub Desktop does not support commit signing](https://help.github.com/en/articles/signing-commits). To sign commits use the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some Git integrations support commit signing, and some don't. It doesn't appear that Atom supports controlling whether commits are signed. However, Git does provide an option to sign all commits which you can use.

If you want to sign all your commits, you can set the configuration option `commit.gpgsign` to `true`, and that will cause all commits to be signed unless you provide the `--no-gpg-sign` option. That should also be true of any commits created in Atom or other tools.

If you want to do it only for this repository, simply edit the `.git/config` file or use  a plain `git config commit.gpgsign true`; if you want to do it for all commits, regardless of repository, you can edit the `.gitconfig` file in your home directory or use the `--global` option in that `git config` invocation.

Comment: Chose `git config --global commit.gpgsign true` and it works - Atom commits are signed as well. Can't devise situation when I do not need signing for now so set it to --global.